# Could not update data: SQL syntax error in my update command

Tags: php, mysql

Just got an error after fixing my code, please consider that the userID in the database is all set to '0'!

**Outprint:**

userID: '23' itemID: '8204'

UPDATE booking SET userID ='23' WHERE itemID ='8204'

**(Error:)**
Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

**UPDATED PHP code second time:**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") OR die(' Could not connect');
$db = mysql_select_db('book1', $con);
if (isset($_GET["userID"]) && isset($_GET["itemID"])){
$userID= (int)$_GET["userID"];
$itemID= (int)$_GET["itemID"];
$test = "userID: '$userID'  itemID: '$itemID'";
echo $test;
echo "<br>";
}
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

echo("UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'"); 
echo "<br>";
$upd = mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'");

$retval = mysql_query($upd, $con);
if(!$retval){
    die('Could not update data: '.mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking");
if($sql === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

echo '<table class="fixed">
    <tr> 
        <th>itemID</th> 
        <th>EMPLOYEE ID</th>
    </tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$row['itemID']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['userID']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

?>

Comment: `SELECT * FROM booking WHERE 1`..... where 1 what?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM booking WHERE 1` -> remove the obviously unneeded `where` condition.

Comment: didn't fix the error, still the same

Comment: Incorrect syntax when you build your query text. It should use a single quote around the text fields i.e. `"UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'"`

Comment: @user3751216 Now that you updated your code, do you still get the same error? If not, please update the error message too.

Comment: @GergoErdosi just updated the error message also

Comment: @user3751216 Can you echo the SQL command before the update? `echo "UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are getting the `$userid` and `$itemid` perfectly.

Then have a look at the `$upd` variable. You are already running `mysql_query`. Change `$upd` to,

```
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'";
```

Then the condition,

```
$retval = mysql_query($upd, $con);
if(!$retval){
    die('Could not update data: '.mysql_error());
} else {
    ....
}
```

It may fix your error.

Comment: You fixed it! Thanks so much for your help, this helped me so much! :)

Comment: For the next step I will find a way so $itemID must exist in the database, if not $retval will trigger die.

Answer (score 3):

Variable interpolation doesn't work with single quotes. Change

```
mysql_query('UPDATE booking SET userID ="$userID" WHERE itemID ="$itemID"');
```

to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'");
```

But please note that this code is vulnerable to SQL injections. See this topic how to prevent it: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: It didn't fix the error either. Yeah I will start use PDO after I get this fuction to work correct.

Comment: @user3751216 Do you have `$userID` and `$itemID` set? In your code they are not defined. Add `$userID = $_GET["userID"]` and `$itemID = $_GET["itemID"]` before calling update.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the data by user id then you will change the code---

**Change this line from**

```
$sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM booking WHERE 1");
```

**to**

```
$sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM booking WHERE 'userID' = '1'");
```

Or if you want to show the data by item id then you will change the code ----

```
$sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM booking WHERE 'itemID' = '1'");
```

Comment: I want to UPDATE the database so the userID will be imported to the database under the same variable as the itemID